# Understanding clone method for non-final classes

Tags: java, clone

I'm reading J. Bloch's effective java and now I'm at the section 39 (making defensive copy). He mentioned that it's not good to make defensive copies through the `clone` method, because:

> Note also that we did not use Date’s clone method to make the
>   defensive copies. Because Date is nonfinal, the clone method **is not**
>   **guaranteed** to return an object whose class is java.util.Date: it could
>   return **an instance of an untrusted subclass** specifically designed for
>   malicious mischief.

The emphasized statement is not apparent to me. Actually, let's consut with the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29). There was no any reference about creating subclasses. The only we can be sure about is this:

> this method creates *a new instance **of the class*** of this object and
>   initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the
>   corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents
>   of the fields are not themselves cloned.

So why did J. Bloch say that it could create ***the subclass***? Couldn't you explain how it implies from the javadoc (I can't see that on my own).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is implicit in the Javadocs quote: The class of "this" object can be a subclass of the declared type of the variable referencing the object (due to polymorphism). The `clone` method is protected so it can be invoked in a subclass of a certain class.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Bar();
        Foo copyOfFoo = createCopyOfFoo(foo);
        System.out.println(copyOfFoo);
    }


    private static Foo createCopyOfFoo(Foo foo) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Foo clone = (Foo) foo.clone();
        return clone;
    }
}

class Foo implements Cloneable {
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    private int x = 1;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bar [x=" + x + "]";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Bar [x=1]

Comment: But the clone itself always return an instance of the dynamic class type  it was invoked on. So, if we invoke the clone method on the excatly java.util.Date we definitely difenetely get the inctance of the Date, right?

Comment: If the method is called on an object of type `Date`, then yes.

Comment: I guess he is assuming that you don't know that you have a java.until.Date and not a subclass.  That subclass could instantiate yet another, untrusted subclass and return that (not obeying the contract for clone() ).

Comment: I still didn't get ...what wrong would happen  if I use